# Notable framerate improvement on Skyrim LE on 20.04.2

Tags: upgrade, games

I have noticed, since the release of 20.04.2 a few days ago, that I am getting significant gameplay improvements in Skyrim LE [Oldrim]. I am using an old card, an HD4870 and I choose to use high quality textures which means I get stuttering quite frequently. However, since the release of 20.04.2 I hardly get any stuttering and gameplay is a lot smoother overall.

What could be responsible for this? Is it the move from kernel 5.4 to 5.8 or something else? I didn't notice much difference after the Mesa upgrade to 20.2.6 but I definitely do now. It's almost like playing on a console.

Maybe others will have noticed improvements in other games also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's quite clear to see what has happened here:

> This is the second point release in the Ubuntu 20.04 LTS series. It
> rolls together all of the software updates, security patches, and bug
> fixes issued to the Focal Fossa to date. **Plus, it intros a new
> hardware enablement stack (HWE) composed of a new kernel and updated
> Linux graphics drivers.**
>
> Linux 5.8 is the big lure of this point release, carried over from
> last October’s Ubuntu 20.10 release. Linux 5.8 introduces improved
> hardware support for AMD Renoir chips, a kernel concurrency sanitiser
> (not that kind) and more exFAT driver improvements.
>
> **Mesa 20.2.6, the last point release in the 20.2.x-series, is included,
> as is libdrm 2.4.102, and xserver 1.20.9.**

https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2021/02/ubuntu-20-04-2-lts-released

So big changes to the kernel and graphics stack have contributed. Maybe the new Mesas needed something in the newer kernel to work to their best potential - but either way, these changes appear to have made a significant difference. It's this combination - rather than one or the other - that seems to be responsible.